# DOJO: Getting JSON result from RESTful API in certain format, and what to do next to parse the result and put it into variables?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, dojo

I have a question about JSON processing (to be displayed within DOJO dgrid)

Quick intermezzo: using XAMPP 3.2.1 and DOJO 1.10 and RESTful API made with "Slim"

This is my JSON result 
(done by using dojo/request/xhr GET method with custom API key as Authorization Header):
I've added indentation here so it is easier to read (but it is a different case in realtime)

```
{"error":false,
 "theworkers":[{"code":"C00001","name":"ALEXANDER"},
               {"code":"C00002","name":"BONAPARTE"},
               {"code":"C00003","name":"CUST"}
              ]
}
```

I've been searching for awhile... and still can't find any good clue,
Tried using JSON.parse but received error message in firebug:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

This is my code which trigger that error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="startButton"> Start! </button>
    <div id="output"> Output here: </br></div>

    <!-- The DOJO Script Goes From Here -->
    <script src="dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="async: 1, parseOnLoad: 1"
    >
    </script>
    <script>
    require(["dojo/request/xhr", 
             "dojo/dom", 
             "dojo/dom-construct", 
             "dojo/json", 
             "dojo/on", 
             "dojo/domReady!"
            ],
            function(xhr, dom, domConst, JSON, on){
              on(dom.byId("startButton"), "click", function(){
                var authKey = "ed75ae5af71ff50b0d3fa859fe102f1e";  
                domConst.place("<p>Requesting...</p>", "output");
                xhr("restinpride/v1/theworkers", {
                  headers: {
                        "Authorization": authKey
                      },  
                  handleAs: "json"
                }).then(function(data){
                    var res = JSON.parse(data);
                    domConst.place("<p>Results are: </p>" + res  + "#" , "output");
                });
              });
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If this is a little bit too much to ask, then firstly I want to ask:

A) How to put "error": false into boolean variable named "isErrorVar" ?

B) How to put those {"code":"C00001", "name":"ALEXANDER"}, and so on (BONAPARTE, CUST)
    into an object (or array) which is easy to work with for dgrid in future use
    as a variable named "theWorkersObj"

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder.... is there any other "well-mannered" way to do the exact same thing? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How Lame... It was due to my knowledge lackness

The answer is:

```
var res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
var isError = res.error;
var theWorkersObj = res.theworkers;
```

The real deal here is, to stringify the data first (which is the result from xhr request)
or else, the code won't work...

Thus, next we can use access the variables like:

```
domConst.place("<p>The error status is: </p>" + isError  + 
               " And The 2nd worker name is " + theWorkersObj[1].name, "output");
```

Result will be:
    "The error status is: false And The 2nd worker name is BONAPARTE"

That's all :D